# firefox webextension alternative to addon clipboard sdk for copying images

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, copy-paste, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to develop a Firefox extension which involves copying an image to the clipboard. In the past, it appears that this was accomplished using the [`clipboard`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/clipboard) addon sdk. However, this is being deprecated so I need to find another way to copy an image to the clipboard. The [docs mentioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Comparison_with_the_Add-on_SDK) using `document.execCommand('copy')` but I cant get that to work for copying images.

From searching the web it seems that its normally not possible to copy an image to the clipboard in Javascript but I was wondering if Firefox has some sort of webextensions API to access the clipboard.

Edit: here is the code I have been using to try to copy images:

```
document.body.appendChild(img);
let range = document.createRange();
range.setStartBefore(img);
range.setEndAfter(img);
range.selectNode(img);
window.getSelection().addRange(range);
var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
document.body.removeChild(img);
```

`img` is an HTML image element.
Nothing happens when it runs, though

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

WebExtensions has `setImageData()`.

> Copy an image that was bundled with the extension:
>
> ```
> // requires the API permission "clipboardWrite"
>
> fetch(browser.runtime.getURL('image.png'))
> .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
> .then(buffer => browser.clipboard.setImageData(buffer, 'png'));
> ```

[clipboard.setImageData() - Mozilla | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/clipboard/setImageData)

Comment: Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. So, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Quoting the most relevant parts on how `setImageData` works, improves the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @adiga Thanks. I added example to my answer.