# enable right-click context menu for firefox webextension popup

Tags: contextmenu, firefox-addon-webextensions

When I open my firefox web extension popup, and try to right click it, nothing happens. How do I enable right-clicking in a firefox web extension popup, so that the context menu appears? I want users to be able to right-click an image and copy it

Comment: Does it work in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it does. I think it is enabled by default for chrome

Comment: You may be able to trigger it by creating a context menu for your popup. Or you may need to copy the image manually. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/contextMenus/create

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't had much luck with copying the image programatically: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43007323/5415895